# Installing Python modules on the (local) Google Earth Engine Docker image

Tags: python, docker, google-earth-engine

I'm new to docker and Google Earth Engine. I'm using [Docker CE](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) and followed the instructions for [locally running GEE Datalab](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-local). Dockers runs fine and I can access the GGE IDE.

I now want to install some additional Python packages. I have no idea how to do this. It seems like the GGE image has `pip` installed but I don't know how to access it. I saw a different SO question about docker that suggested you need to edit the image itself to add the `pip install` commands, but I can't find the actual docker image on my machine. What is the correct way to install additional Python packages for use with Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Dockerfile` and build a new image for extending those additional python packages. So in one folder you should have a `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt`.

**Dockerfile** should be like:

```
FROM <GEE_image>
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then run `docker build <location_of_dockerfile> -t <new_image_name>` then just run it.

Or another method would be to just ssh inside the existing GEE container like `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` and manually install the additional python packages there.

**TAKE NOTE:** You can not change an image owned by anyone. You can just extend it and create your own

Comment: I tried extending the image with your instructions and it worked! The only hiccup was that I couldn't get it to run just with `docker run <new_image_name>`, I had to modify the GEE command and use that, i.e. `docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080" -v "%WORKSPACE%:/content" -e "PROJECT_ID=%GCP_PROJECT_ID%" <new_image_name>`.

Comment: Good to hear! Seems like environment variables are important to run this as a container. It's also important to read documentation of an image by the way